# How well informed are the Russian public about the recent Wagner mutiny?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, wagner-pmc

The recent mutiny by the Wagner Group, controlled by [Yevgeny Prigozhin](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/jun/24/yevgeny-prigozhin-wagner-uprising-likely-to-help-ukraine-by-draining-russian-resources) played out in real-time on TV around the world.  The Russian people will have watched [Putin's statement](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/jun/24/vladimir-putin-russia-wagner-statement-full) about the mutiny but how well informed are they more generally?  Do they know who Wagner are, who Yevgeny Prigozhin is and what his demands were given the [reporting restrictions in the Russian media](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/04/world/europe/russia-censorship-media-crackdown.html)?

Comment: Can you say what exactly you mean of informed, what should rus public to know about wagner mutiny? what is a criterium of well informing?

Comment: What is the criteria for evaluating *well informed*? Comparative to western public? Or does it imply knowing certain facts about Wagner and Progozhin (please add the list to the OP)? Or specific elements of the events (please add to the OP)?

Comment: @RogerVadim  For 'well informed' I asked: "Do they know who Wagner are, who Yevgeny Prigozhin is and what his demands were?",  I guess you could add "were they aware of the capture of Rostov on Don and the movement towards Moscow?"

Comment: *"Do they know who Wagner are, who Yevgeny Prigozhin is?"* - knowing these things is very far from being ***well** informed*. (Even though I am aware that some people in Russia, like in the US may not know who their president is.) Also, Russia is a country with 100+ millions of population - how many of them have to know Wagner and Prigozhin for being considered well informed as a nation/people/etc.?

Comment: @RogerVadim  I think you've hit the nail on the head - what proportion of the Russian people are (or were, since they'll probably be getting better informed very fast at the moment) familiar with Wagner, Prigozhin, the events in Rostov and Voronezh etc.?

Comment: I think it would be better to rewrite the question is such specific terms - just to conform with the general SE policy (seeing the number of votes and answers I doubt that it would be closed as ambiguous, despite my criticism. I don't vote to close, since it would be unprincipled to do so after having posted an answer.)

Comment: None of the answers so far actually answer the question.  They address the question how well Russians **could** be informed, if they were actively looking for information.  In reality, most people do not go through this effort.

Comment: I think all the questions mention a lot of Internet media services data.  But the key statistic that makes that relevant (or not) is what percent of the households have an Internet access.  And none of the answers discuss this point.  Maybe the question can be amended to make the point that it's not relevant what can be found on any one particular Internet media service unless there is also the general information available on how many households have Internet.

Answer (score 18):

Many officially banned and blocked services representing the Russian independent  press (pro-Russian readers would word this differently) have apps for mobile phones. These apps are often able to bypass the blocking with the flip of the switch. As they say:

[image]

Translation:

> In any shitty situation, the Kremlin destroys the Internet. Be sure to download the Meduza app. It works in Russia without VPN.

By March 2022, Meduza's website alone had [between 12 and 18 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meduza) monthly visitors.

Your source contains reference to some mysterious tweet that Novaya Gazeta have removed all information about the Russia-Ukraine conflict. What do they want to say by this? [Novaya Gazeta EU](https://novayagazeta.eu/) is one of my main sources of information, that used to be and remains full of in depth coverage of this war.

Hence the information is available in Russia, who wants to get it. Those passively consuming news from the always-on radio in the kitchen is more a problem.

Comment: It has to be said that "Those passively consuming news from the always-on radio in the kitchen" are a problem in the West as well :-/

Comment: Seems that this "foreign and emigration press" does have correspondents in Russia and Ukraine, as well as the history of the honest reporting.

Comment: Undoubtedly. But when did last hear what's typically played on the radio in a Western kitchen? I'd hardly call a diet of regurgitated popular tunes, celebrity news, traffic reports and state-sanctioned gambling conducive to a well-informed public.

Comment: +1  I guess the ability to get around the blocking and the motivation to do so are major factors in my question.  "These apps are often able to bypass the blocking with the flip of the switch."  I didn't know that.  The more difficult it is to do something the less likely that people will try.  But then if you aren't interested or buy the party line it doesn't matter how many independent information sources there are, you're not going to look at them.

Comment: @DaveGremlin if the app etc. can get around blocking and the routers are controlled by (an ally of) the state, the end result could be unpleasant. Which is why termination of long-wave AM broadcasts by the BBC etc., which could be picked up on a simple receiver with no chance of tracking, is such a big deal.

Comment: In the end, I don't believe that Russian public actually consumes a lot of international/emigrant media, with possible exception of YouTube channels. The quality of their coverage is also questionable.

Comment: This does not answer the question how well-informed Russians are.  It answers the (different) question how well-informed Russians can be if they choose to actively search for information.

Comment: Added some stats then

Answer (score 10):

Prigozhin's main communication channel throughout the mutiny was recording and sending Telegram voice messages in Russian to his [channel](https://t.me/concordgroup_official).

That makes Russians the prime audience to know all the ins and outs of the event, and produce many, many memes about it.

All of the reactions to that are also on Telegram. Videos or Wagner in Rostov. Footage of skirmishes between Wagner and MoD. Opinions of various military figures. Kadyrov's announcements. Reactions to Putin's speech. Tracking of Wagner's movements.

I would say the only things which were not sourced on Telegram are Putin's speech (TV) and movement of Wagner's columns towards Moscow (respective regional news outlets).

The Western press (by example of The Guardian) was several hours late into their coverage, still giving yesterday's highlights as the Rostov was already overrun. Generally, they lack any sources in LDNR militias/Army/Wagner corps and only relay the same Telegram trends.

Comment: I don't think Prigozhin's official channel should be the primary source for "all the ins and outs" in this case, even though it's important.

Comment: I've expanded the answer.

Comment: How widely used is Telegram?  Is it used more by younger people or a particular demographic?

Comment: As per Junemann's research of year ago, Telegram is the main source of news for people of Moscow aged 35 or less.

Comment: @alamar that is about as uninformative as it can get.  Moscow demographics are entirely different from the rest of the country.

Comment: I don't have better data, but the idea here is that if >10% of Russians get their data from Telegram and it happens to be important, they would surely relay it to all their acquintances via WhatsApp/VK/spoken word.

Answer (score 10):

Over the last two months (maybe a little more) before the coup, there was already a ban on mentioning Wagner and Prigozhin in all Russian media. None of the official channels and army of Z-propagandists have mentioned any of those names. Instead of it they were using general 'dobrovolcheskiye otriadi' (which means volunteer military units from general population, not drafted who decided to fight). Only some of Z-telegrams who were somehow (or a lot) affiliated with Prigozhin were using those names.

During the coup, VK, ‎Odnoklassniki (popular social networks controlled by Putin) blocked official channels from Prigozhin and highlighting of these events, on orders from Putin's administration. Same for the search engine Yandex (also controlled by Putin).

Regarding how widely Prigozhin is known, it is a very hard question to even ask properly. As there are many gradations of 'know' starting from somewhere heard this name but have no idea what it means to actively following and knowing what he is doing now. The only more or less credible poll number I found is from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/live/DernrMPB5LY?feature=share&t=2220), which state that

- as of Dec: 40% of people didn't even knew such name. And 50% of people who knew see him positively.
- as of June: 17% of people didn't even knew such name. And 61% of people who knew see him positively.

In my opinion those percentages of people who didn't even knew such name is pretty staggering for a person of such caliber who has done a lot to promote himself and is playing one of the important roles in the war.

---

I also think that being informed about something and understanding the situation are very different concepts. We are speaking about a population which believes that:

- 'special military operation' is going according to plan. The facts that it is lasting almost 500 days, groups of armed men attacking Russia, military objects in the rear of Russia are being destroyed, drones are flying around Kremlin are not making a dent in this belief
- there are no losses on Russian side (later was changed to losses are minimum). Where are all those men going and why are they not even sending messages is a mystery (probably just do not have access to cell phone over hundreds of days)
- Russia is destroying huge amount of equipment every day. The fact that if you will just add all those claimed destroyed equipment it is order of magnitude bigger than all the equipment that was sent and was in Ukraine, does not bother anyone

---

Person asked **how official state covered event**

As with every totalitarian regime during panic:

- propagandists didn't know what to do (were silent) either by being afraid to choose side or were not sure what to tell. As there are literally hundred of propagandist (people who will tell everything that gov wants to hear) in russia (this is a very lucrative profession) so here I will mention only s-tier one. [Margarita Simonyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarita_Simonyan) has not not told anything until the very end (until the coup ended) and afterwards told that she didn't know and were on the boat trip (a guy who claimed that everyone has internet everywhere in russia: seems like Margarita was not able to connect). Another one [Vladimir Solovyov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Solovyov_(TV_presenter)) whose usual rhetoric consists of shouting about nuclear bombing of European capitals and creating killing squads to execute everyone who is against the war, was telling in very mild tones that Wagner's actions are questionable.
- Most of the governors were telling `we are with president` without telling with which one (the one that fly away in panic from moscow) or potentially the new one. Some of them were congratulating youth with the [day of youth](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%B8_(%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)) (I am not joking, even Putin has done so).
- Kadyrov was also silent for a long long time. Then told that his brave guys are going to fix everything (create a few more tik-toks). But his guys never arrived and they told that they are [stuck in traffic](https://socportal.info/ru/news/liudi-skaplivaiutsya-v-tcentre-rostova-nachalis-stychki-vagnera-razoruzhaiut-kadyrovtcev/)
- Generals were begging Prigozhin to stop, and remember the good times when they were all friends. Some [tried to look like not so scared](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/nBSuC5c-jOQ), while another [was mumbling and looked like he will cry](https://twitter.com/sambendett/status/1672361531034460162). During this time Prighozin was schooling the ones in Rostov asking them why are they so pathetic. BTW now months ago we know that this has not saved many of the generals as they are now missing. The most well known is [Surovikin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Surovikin)
- Putin with his [briefcases](https://www.businessinsider.com/putin-bodyguards-collect-his-poop-every-time-travels-abroad-report-2022-6) has probably left Moscow in panic as his [plane was spotted leaving Moscow](https://www.businessinsider.com/putin-presidential-plane-spotted-leaving-moscow-amid-wagner-uprising-2023-6). His speaker Peskov told that Putin is in Moscow and as he was never spotted lying then this is definitely correct and the plane just likes to fly. Similar was seen by many other top level official.
- In Putin's [speech he again tried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnZZiUZquqU) to be a historian, was telling how everyone takes advantage of russia (first 3:45 mins out of 5:30) and then was telling how swift and severe his actions would be and how he will punish everyone involved. We all know how it ended up (everyone pardoned, Prigozhin went for vacation to [Belarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Lukashenko) (BTW, this created some shit-storm in [russists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruscism) z-channels (as 6 helicopters and one plane with people were killed but Putin said later that no blood was spilled). That was one of the most pathetic speech in a history of speeches: try for yourself to listen to it and ask yourself "have you understood what events he was talking about?". I have not.

Comment: This answer could be improved if it addressed how official Russian state media have covered recent events.

Comment: @gerrit added this information.

Comment: Well, vacation ended with a grenade in a plane, according to Putin. It's also interesting that he broke that version of events personally.

Comment: @Fizz according to putin, russia has the second strongest army in the word, people in europe are dying from hunger and russia is the best country with amazing economy, wealthy people. Maybe you should stop thinking about the version of an old fart who is unable to finish a sentence without lying?

Answer (score 0):

> How well informed are the Russian public about the recent Wagner mutiny?

*How well...?* implies a comparison to something - here, probably, a comparison to the western public.

The answer is: Russians are probably informed just as good as the western public or even better: everyone has access to the internet. Moreover, Russians have the advantage of understanding information from "raw" sources in Russian, as it appears in real time, whereas westerners have to rely in the correspondents and translation.

**Update** (Expanding in response to the comments)
There are some premises not explicitly stated in the OP:

- Most people do not want to actively seek information and would rely on that provided by the mainstream (or government) media or the media affiliated with the side that they prefer. We see it vividly, e.g., in the perceptions of Republicans and Democrats in the US, and the media catering to this or that side (like Fox/CNN or WSJ/NYT for more educated.) Do we have reason to think that Russians are prone to deceiving themselves than westerners?
- There is also the Cold War stereotype that non-Democratic governments control their population via controlling their access to information. Indeed, during the Cold War this was largely the case, since it was technically possible to limit access to information: both media, but also private communication (international phone calls were recorded in the USSR, the letters were read, and in early 80s the internet access was sufficiently rare to read all the emails). This however was not quite true even in the Soviet times - people could complete their knowledge using the word-of-mouth, [Samizdat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samizdat), and by listening to foreign broadcasts in Russian (like those by BBC or the Voice of America.) This is even less the case today, when private communications cannot be controlled (beyond the measures similar to those of NSA, introduced under GW Bush and Obama administrations) and independent public channels (notably in the internet) are too abundant to be controlled.
- Given the historical background, describe above, one can even assume that Russians are less likely to trust government media than their western counterparts (indeed, have you ever felt surprised when western media show protesters in places like Iran or Syria carry placards in English?)

Answer (score -2):

This question is based on wrong, pre-conceived notions popular in the west about Russians - what does "well informed" mean?

*Even teens* know how to use VPN apps in smartphones to access blocked sites. Even teens use **Telegram**, which is a very popular social media and messenger platform in Russia. **And no Russian is jailed for reading foreign information.(1)**

While it is not hard (for the government) to control what is broadcast on Russian Television, most Russians also have access to the internet.

And while smartphone users, who access the internet on their phones can easily be identified by SIM cards and [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) (as mobile connections issued in Russia, like many other countries, are linked with personal government issued ids like passport) Russians are not prosecuted by the government for getting information from  Medusa, TG-channels, BBC, NYT etc. YouTube is completely and freely accessible in Russia.

It is not as if Russians all turn to Chinese and North Korean media news as alternatives - because there is a language barrier that is not easily overcome.

**Let's think what kind of instruments for *well informing* ordinary Russians have**:

English language sources are more easily accessible to Russians because the **Yandex** browser (a popular web browser by a Russian Tech corporation) can even [translate YouTube videos in real time while it is streamed](https://habr.com/ru/companies/yandex/articles/680596/). This is commonly used by many Russian to access information that is in English as Yandex provides good translation of English language to Russian (better than Google). While it may fall short of the standard of human translation, even 80-90% of translation accuracy is enough to understand the subject matter of the translated video.

Also on PC version is available function to translation not a whole web page, but [only the part of the text, phrase or word](https://habr.com/ru/companies/yandex/articles/576438/#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.).

Russians also have access to [Russia Today (RT)](https://www.rt.com/) - a Russians media agency that was very popular in EU and USA too before it was blocked.

I don't think that "*bananas republics*" allow their citizens so many avenues for self-information, including foreign ones.

So when you suppose Russians of not being *informed*, perhaps you should consider how well-informed you yourself are and whether you are prejudiced and have blindly accepted some propaganda from your own government about Russia and Russians?

**About RT being a Russian Propaganda Outlet**

RT still allows users to comment on their article freely with a voting system that mostly remains unmoderated for several hours, while main part of people are reading the post. Which western mainstream media still allows free comments in real time? BBC had in, let me remember, in 2014? And even then, comments function was not available for all articles and in 2014 this function was removed without back.

[**INO-TV**](https://russian.rt.com/inotv) - this is another  important service by RT where Russian readers can read foreign articles about Russia, that have already been translated to Russian. The source for these articles include [TIMES](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Times-novaya-antivoennaya-partiya-Vagenkneht) (US), [FOX](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Fox-udobnij-povod-otvlechsya-) (US), [Spigel](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Spiegel-mi-ne-v-pervih) (German), [ABC](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/ABC-ne-priveli-ubeditelnih-dovodov) (US), [Independent](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Independent-tisyachi-nasilnikov-v-Velikobritanii) (UK), [Washington Post](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Odnim--povod-dlya-gordosti) (US), [Atlantic](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Atlantic-Ukraine-v-kontrnastuplenii-pridyotsya) (UK), [Deutschlandfunk](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Deutschlandfunk-mirnie-peregovori-po-Ukraine) (German), [Yonhop](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Yonhap-KNDR-obvinila-SSHA-v) (Korean) etc. (note that all of these translated articles are recent, of today morning 26 june 2023).

So, among the Russians who read RT frequently as their main media source, do you think they are they not "*well informed*"? Most of you may not be familiar with these media sources but every Russian who reads RT knows about these foreign media agencies as they read the translated news from them every day for free. Do any western media agency provide a similar service that give them such outsider perspective of their country? I think they do not.

**Note:** I found out that the recordings of United Nations meetings exist only because [RT shows them in original and live broadcasting](https://russian.rt.com/world/article/969368-zasedanie-sovet-bezopasnost-oon#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C%2028%20%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9D.%20RT%20%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E.) But on Youtube I can't see those videos and get the mesage that "**Видео недоступно**. Eго нельзя посмотреть в вашей стране."(Translation: The video is banned in your country (Russia) - the video is banned by Youtube, not from RT or Russia side. I can still find [the video record in Russian websites](https://rutube.ru/video/dcdcff4ed46dca72ab829bd9cde8c61e/) that i can't find in Youtube searching.

Or is the implication that Russian state sponsored media only indulge in blind propaanda? If yes, then obviously Russians are not *well informed*.

Ok, lets check how *well informed* were Russians about Wagner and Prigozhin in Rostov, by RT and RBC (state sponsored media of Russia):

- ["В сети появились кадры встречи Пригожина с замминистром обороны России Евкуровым"](https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/1166031-prigozhin-vstrecha-evkurov-alekseev) 24 june 2023, 08:04 (Translate: *Footage of Prigozhin's meeting with Russian Deputy Defense Minister Yevkurov appeared online*)

> "*Пригожин заявил, что бойцы «ЧВК Вагнер» блокировали Ростов-на-Дону, и пригрозил пойти на Москву, потребовал встречи с главой Минобороны и Генштаба.*" (Translation: *Prigozhin said that the fighters of the "PMCS Wagner" blocked Rostov-on-Don, and threatened to go to Moscow, demanded a meeting with the head of the Defense Ministry and the General Staff*).

- ["Военкор рассказал об установленных на въезде в Ростов-на-Дону блокпостах"](https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/1166124-blokposty-rostov-na-donu) 24 июня 2023, 12:09 (Translation: *The military commander told about the checkpoints installed at the entrance to Rostov-on-Don*)
- [Взрывы и стрельба](https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/1166176-shtab-yuvo-vystrely) (Translation: *Explosions and shooting*), [минирование въезда в Ростов](https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/1166203-chvk-vagner-miny) (Translation: *Mining of the entrance to Rostov*).
- [Воронеж, пожар на нефтебазе.](https://russian.rt.com/russia/video/1166174-v-voronezhe-gorit-neftebaza) 24 june 2023, 13:57 (Translation: *Voronezh, a fire at an oil depot.*)

But RT mostly reported news fragments without whole narrative.

But another official Russian media(available on TV and web) - [**RBC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBK_Group), reported the conflict in more detail for the time point in 19~ PM, also including [the attack on helicopter, that become the cause of the oil-tank burning in Voronezh](https://tv.rbc.ru/archive/chez/649720762ae59675bc66f4ee) - look at 9:00 min of the video. (RBC ЧЭЗ(Что это значит? / What does this mean?)

- RBC also has information [About Prigozhin and Wagner Group](https://tv.rbc.ru/archive/chez/649720762ae59675bc66f4ee) at 25:00 min.
- ["Крушение Ил-18(предположительно) под Воронежем"](https://tv.rbc.ru/archive/news/6496d4ac2ae59675bc66f4e8) look at 7:05min.  24 june 2023 14:00 RBC/TG Baza. (Translation: *IL-18 crash (presumably) near Voronezh*).
- And at the end officially words from president Putin - [Путин поблагодарил за самопожертвование летчиков, сбитых во время мятежа](https://www.rbc.ru/politics/26/06/2023/6499e8d89a7947970dfdcbec) (Translation: *Putin appreciates the self-sacrifice of the pilots shot down during the mutiny*).

Every Russian is also free to read the wikipage on Prigozhin and about [Wagner](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%92%D0%9A_%C2%AB%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%C2%BB) in [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) and [English versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_Group).

And also [Путин назвал расходы бюджета на содержание ЧВК «Вагнер»)](https://www.rbc.ru/politics/27/06/2023/649ad0de9a7947730bb9b3ba?from=from_main_2)(Translation: *Putin indicated the budget expenditures for the maintenance of the Wagner PMCs* +(and income of [Concord group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord_Management_and_Consulting))

I also enjoyed this RT post's format - [podcast on original language with translation under](https://russian.rt.com/inotv/2023-06-26/Redacted-o-myatezhe-Prigozhina-ne). I think it is better then "well informed", but it is a *great informed standarts*, even if it is *propaganda* (or which of medias is not a propaganda?). *Ow, some people thought that this blogger is from RT, but nope he is independent from RT and Russian Govt and [Redacted](https://www.youtube.com/@RedactedNews/about) is not ever original russian propaganda, but USA.*

So i can say with confidence that Russians are actually the most *well informed* and have better instruments to get free information from most of world media services(whatever *to be well informed* means).

(**1**) In the reason that my comments are disappearing by itself i have to answer here on "*It took me 2 mins to create a russian search query and find that this is fake...*" by @Salvador Dali. Lets read a header of the post ["Пассажирку рейса Москва—Владикавказ задержали за чтение книги на украинском языке"](https://moskvichmag.ru/novosti/passazhirku-rejsa-moskva-vladikavkaz-zaderzhali-za-chtenie-knigi-na-ukrainskom-yazyke/)(A woman passenger on the Moscow—Vladikavkaz flight was **arrested** (by police) for reading a book in Ukrainian).  ***Arrest by police*** in terms meaning is not same as a ***jailing***(see [different between arrest and jail](https://wikidiff.com/jail/arrest). ). So "*If they want to jail you for breathing the air of free russia, they will do this in a minute."* - that is a lie with the confusion of meanings. And ofc phrase that the reason was "reading a book in Ukrainian" is used for provoking, there was many other reasons to provoke the police for cheking(arrest here mean checking) her person.

**Summary**:

Are the Russian "well informed"?

- Most of Russians know how to use Ethernet, VPN, and other free getting information ways.
- Russians are **free to get** any information without any outcome persecution. Do not confuse "be free to get" and "be free to spread".
- Russians have original tools for easy translation texts, parts of texts, and even videos, and even while streaming. i think this tools are the best and easiest in usage for this moments.
- Russian's official media give different(foreign also) view points, give references on this points and medias in original format and/or it decent translation on Russian language without any cutting or clipping. Also they usually give source links or notice, for example on Telegram-channels, where the information was got of.
- Russians have not any real limits of getting information from Russian side, or that can avoided without any judgement, but Russian have limits of getting information from foreign services like Youtube, that do [banned and deleted Russian political/culture-like bloggers with more the several millions of followers out of any law](https://www.rbc.ru/technology_and_media/04/08/2022/62ebf86b9a7947dc08c57d5c), and/or restrict content for Russian users unilaterally like UN meeting of 28/02/22.

Comment: @sfxedit Hehe you cut the story about Tucker), but thanks a lot, but i ll fix some

Comment: "has good information, even if it is propaganda (which media is not a propaganda?)" - you need to work really, really hard to find propaganda of such poisonous level on any "official" media in the West. It's beyond ridiculous. Prigozhin being "by all accounts" a tool of the West, all that. Arguably, after reading RT one is _less_ informed than before.

Comment: This post addresses how well Russians could be informed if they followed certain sources, but it does not address if they actually do.  One could have state and independent press coverage all day, but people who watch cat videos on tiktok will not be well-informed.

Comment: @Zeus  "really hard to find propaganda of such poisonous level on any "official" media in the West." - so, you think that soft unnoticeable propaganda is better then clearly propaganda? "Prigozhin being "by all accounts" a tool of the West" - where did you read this?

Comment: It's literally in your RT link. Original: "Пригожин, человек, который по всем параметрам является орудием Запада".

Comment: @Zeus *Original: "Пригожин, человек, который по всем параметрам является орудием Запада"* - it is  not ever RT original text or official rus point, it is foreign blogger, but RT translate his opinion and make it available rus auditory. Stop read headers only)

Comment: You are not fluent in English and so your answer was difficult to understand. I removed the Tucker reference because I didn't get it. Honestly, your answer was more of a confrontational rant which isn't encouraged here, and hence I tried to tone it down. Do note that SEs are not discussion sites but meant to provide factual answers. So just present the facts without taking a confrontational tone. **Note**: You don't have to provide additional commentary within your answers to others who edit your post. The place for that is the [Edit Summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289107/648258).

Comment: @sfxedit you had deleted not only about Tucker, but about DARPA too, and you d inverted my senses)

Comment: @άνθρωπος You can add back anything I have deleted if you feel it is relevant to your answer. But note that I have only deleted stuff I couldn't really understand and / or is just irrelevant (like Tucker or Darpa etc.) and doesn't provide more meaning to your answer. Long answers do not necessarily mean better quality answers - always try to remove the irrelevant / minor stuffs that don't really add any value to your answer.

Comment: @sfxedit DARPA - all letters are capital, it is  abbreviation. I add this in reason that some people tell something like Telegram is under FSB(russian agents) observation.  So i think that is a "well informing" to tell about DARPA's techs, because Ethernet and Smartphones are USA military techs, i think all must to know this, similar to Snowden. Snowden can't to do inform USA society, because he run to Russia, and Russians are informed about observing methods. Snowden was an CIA and ANB agent, you know?

Comment: @sfxedit and about "a confrontational rant" - is it politics SE or i got mistake? Politics without confrontation is it real?

Comment: I'd say that teens are the most likely social group to understand VPNs and know how to use them.

Comment: @άνθρωπος I do know about DARPA. But like I pointed out, when someone is asking here how well-informed Russians are about something, which is better - an answer that points out how Russians have access to many sources of information or an answer that discusses about political propaganda, cold war, internet invented by US defence agency, cell-phones SIM and IMEI tracking etc. etc.? Po.SE is a question and answer site - just focus on the question asked. Not on other users answering the question because, yes, everyone has different political views and bias. So clarify instead of confronting.

Comment: And because Po.SE is a Q & A site, and not a discussion site, all comments below answers that are not specifically on topic to it will be deleted (including comments like this). Your answer was not bad at all (except for the rant) - all I am saying is that you could be more polite and just stick to the facts. Sometimes the people who ask the questions here (like this questioner) may genuinely be ignorant - perhaps even due to propaganda. So just educate them with facts - like you tried here (but without being confrontational, even if someone doesn't like your answer).

Comment: Also note that if you don't like any edit I or others make to your answer, you can change it back - you are under no obligations to accept such edits (even if an edit made helpfully).